# Can't figure out how to group input settings into a preset so I don't have to keep changing the input settings on my indicator for each timeframe

Tags: input

I wrote a buy/sell indicator using PineScript and I have different values for each timeframe (moving average lengths, signal smoothing, period, etc). Basically, I wanna create a preset for each timeframe. Something like this:

preset = input.string(title='Preset', defval='Normal', options=['Normal', 'Sensitive', 'Very Sensitive'])

```
if preset == 'Normal'
    length_ma1_normal := 50
    length_ma2_normal := 200
plot(?) 
if preset == 'Sensitive'
    length_ma1_normal := 50
    length_ma2_normal := 100
plot(?)
```

My buy/sell signals get triggered based on ema crossovers, macd, etc. Let's say I choose "Normal", I want the chart to plot labels based on 50/200 ema, "Sensitive" triggers 21/50 and so on. When I choose a different preset they all should plot only what the values for each preset are. Basically, the buy/sell signals are triggered based off 4 parameters and is it possible to plot all 4 (each preset has different values) for each preset?
[I'm looking to do something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTd2W.jpg)